# How to understand the last character 枚 in 福田熊治良枚

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji, readings, reading-comprehension

In the context of a C19th print of the actor Iwai Hanshirō, the publisher’s name and address is included: 長谷川丁十九バンチ  福田熊治良枚. How should the last character 枚 that comes after *Hasegawachō jūku banchi Fukuda Kumajirō*  be understood and read? The references I have for 枚, *mai*, are “counter for flat objects (e.g. sheets of paper),” or *bira*, “bill, handbill, flier, leaflet, poster, placard.” Why is it placed directly after the name of the publisher Fukuda Kumajirō? I often see *shuppanjin* (出版人), where the suffix *jin* (人, じん) attaches to the name of the occupation, and there is also *hanmoto* (版元).

---

Edit (after Naruto's request to include an image):

[image]

The characters in the cartouche were not all equally clear. I have increased the contrast in Photoshop. Yes, the character is 板, not 枚.

Comment: Could you share the original image if you have one? After looking at a few images from "長谷川丁十九バンチ福田熊治良" available online ([this](https://bit.ly/2MVGLrN), [this](http://archive.library.metro.tokyo.jp/da/detail?tilcod=0000000003-00012240) and [this](http://archive.library.metro.tokyo.jp/da/detail?tilcod=0000000003-00007674)), I felt this 枚 might be part of a different word that happens to be adjacent.

Comment: Hmm, I found that this publisher used [出板 instead of 出版](https://koshomizutama.wordpress.com/2017/10/22/%E6%98%8E%E6%B2%BB%E3%80%80%E6%B5%AE%E4%B8%96%E7%B5%B5%E3%80%80%E5%B0%8F%E6%9E%97%E6%B8%85%E8%A6%AA%E3%80%80%E7%A6%8F%E7%94%B0%E7%86%8A%E6%B2%BB%E8%89%AF%E3%80%80%E5%B7%9D%E7%AB%AF%E7%8E%89%E7%AB%A0/), and that [板 was a common kanji](http://www.book-seishindo.jp/2012_tanq/tanq_2012B-08.pdf) in the publishing industry in those days. 板 makes sense as a suffix meaning "printed by ～". Are you sure you are seeing 枚, not 板?

Comment: http://www.ne.jp/asahi/tako1/tako2/art/catalog88.htm

Comment: naruto and @droooze, I have increased the tonal contrast and uploaded the image... yes, it is my mistake, it is 板, not 枚, the line was faint. That said, the character 板 stands alone (opposed to its use in 板画 or 出板), so I am uncertain as to how it should be pronounced/read... _han_? The use of 板 alone is in keeping with the final print example provided by droooze.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kanji is 板, not 枚. It says:

> 守川音治良画 = designed by 守川音治良
>   福田熊治良**板** = printed/published by 福田熊治良

板 means "board" in modern Japanese, but [板 was used like modern 版](http://www.book-seishindo.jp/2012_tanq/tanq_2012B-08.pdf) ("print" or "publish") in the past. As for the reading, I'm not sure, but はん and ばん seem equally reasonable to me in this context.